# how to shape vertical line as curved at corners?

Tags: android, android-layout

simply i attached the required output image.within the braces, i need a textviews..

[image]

i tried with below code:

```
<View
                    android:layout_width="3dp"
                    android:layout_height="90dp"
                    android:visibility="visible"
                    android:background="@drawable/straight_line" />
```

```
<corners
    android:bottomLeftRadius="15dp"
    android:bottomRightRadius="5dp"
    android:topLeftRadius="15dp"
    android:topRightRadius="5dp" />
<size
    android:height="6dp" />
<solid
    android:color="@color/black" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="@drawable/side_bar" >
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:text="First Name " />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:text="First Name " />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:text="First Name " />
</LinearLayout>
```

And set background using this drawable

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:bottom="-2dp"
        android:left="2dp"
        android:right="2dp"
        android:top="-3dp">
        <shape>
            <stroke
                android:width="2dp"
                android:color="#161616" />
            <corners
                android:bottomLeftRadius="15dp"
                android:bottomRightRadius="15dp"
                android:topLeftRadius="15dp"
                android:topRightRadius="15dp" />
        </shape>

    </item>
    </layer-list>
```

your Output like this..

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using layer-list drawable.

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item
    android:bottom="-2dp"
    android:left="2dp"
    android:right="2dp"
    android:top="-2dp">
    <shape>
        <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
        <stroke
            android:width="@dimen/border_size"
            android:color="@color/black_30" />
        <corners
            android:bottomLeftRadius="15dp"
            android:bottomRightRadius="15dp"
            android:topLeftRadius="15dp"
            android:topRightRadius="15dp" />
    </shape>

</item>
```

Comment: but its not applicable when i set background using  this drawable.

Comment: It&#39;s is applicable it&#39;s layer list drawble ..set as background to view in xml. Check on real device .

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to use 9-patch images to have this type of background. You can refer this like as a reference http://tekeye.uk/android/examples/ui/android-9-patch-image-files